# Log Scale Issue in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to create a scatter plot. The plot is based on 100,000 records and shown in the image 1. But when I try to use log scale on x-axis the shape changes to what is shown in image 2. It seems like only half of the plot is shown. I have tried different solutions but nothing has worked so far.

[plot without log scale (x-axis)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kozK0.png)
[plot with log scale (x-axis)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmFoi.png)

Any ideas what is causing this? Below is the code I am using to create the plot.

```
plt.scatter(proj_list, span_list_new)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xlabel("Number of Projects (log scale)")
plt.ylabel("Span (years)")
plt.show()
```

Comment: That's a bug which is caused by negative numbers being present in the data. In such case you can either filter out the negative numbers first, or set the limits manually.

Comment: There were no negative values, but I did find some unexpected zero values which were causing this issue. Removing those zeros fixed it. Thanks!